# Trying to get HTTP headers, etc. from AWS Gateway in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm sure there is an easy answer for this, but I'm only finding JS/Node examples on Amazon's site.

I'm trying to get the full request from the Gateway to pass to the AWS Lambda. I know you can build your own POJO, and I've got that working for a simple app. It looks like I really want to be using Lambda proxy integration, but I can't figure out what Amazon classes the RequestHandler expects for the Request and Response if I use the proxy integration.

My questions are:

1. Am I going down the right path for getting the complete request using the Lambda proxy integration?
2. What Java classes should I be using in the RequestHandler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following handler structure:

```
@Override
class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,Object>, Map<String,Object>> {
    public Map<String,Object> handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input, Context context) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Your response object should be a Map with

- statusCode: HTTP response code (e.g., 200)
- headers: a Map of HTTP headers (e.g., "Content-type"="application/json")
- body: the actual response content (described by the Content-Type header)